# C#: Spaces around ! operator, how to interpret?

Tags: c#

I don't read C# every day, and am reading a recent commit with something that is throwing me:

```
if (( length > maxLength) && ! IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType))
do_something;
```

I am having trouble mentally parsing the && and ! operators, specifically because the ! operator has a space after it.

The question can be distilled to:

Is (with space)

```
if (( length > maxLength) && ! IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType))
```

the same as (without space):

```
if (( length > maxLength) && !IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType))
```

The concrete questions are:

- Is IsTable() , whether true or false, changing the evaluation?
- Is the space after ! basically letting the first eval do all the work?

Or, is there something I am missing about acceptable syntax.

Comment: define *controlling*

Comment: You're having problem ... "parsing" that? Are you trying to read that programatically or just trying to understand what it does?
the bang operator stands for "not" and its usually attached to whatever is immediately to the right of it.

Comment: IsTable is called only if length > maxlength is true. If it is true then, the IsTable is called and if it returns false then the logical NOT operator (!) is applied to the false return value and thus the _do_something_ is executed. Spaces are meaningless,

Comment: @Felype OP updated, thank you

Comment: @Steve I think you pegged my q. Does the space after the !  carry any meaning?  OP enhanced.

Comment: the space is irelevant  (if the compiler / parser let you put it there)

Comment: `Ctrl+K` and `Ctrl+D` will fix it for you, so yes, spacing is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, the `&&` operator means that the 2nd condition is examined only if the 1st condition is `true`.

So only if `(length > maxLength)` is `true`, then the `!IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType)` condition is examined.

When C# compiles, it disregards spaces after most operators, such as `!`. So the space after `!` is meaningless.

```
! IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType)
```

is just like:

```
!IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType)
```

and it means that if `IsTable(furniture.FurnitureType)` is `true`, it results as `false`, and the other way around.

So, your entire `if` clause will be `true` only if `length > maxLength` and your `FurnitureType` is not a table. A chair, a desk, a closet or even a stool. But not a table.

Comment: It is true that space after operators doesn't mean anything but spaces near operators may mean something if it separates one operator from another. A contrived example would be that `+ + a` is not the same as `++ a` or `++a`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for pointing that out. I rephrased my answer.

Comment: Not really necessary if you ask me, I pointed it out just to nitpick about a very contrived corner case :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Fair call, but this conversation is specific to boolean operators. Is it fair to say that spaces are meaningless vis a vis boolean operators?

Comment: Well, a contrived example like the one I showed with the `++` vs `+ +` would have to find a similar case using `|` or `&`. The `&` operator can also be used to take the address of a variable in unsafe code but now I feel like I'm fishing for cornercases, I'd say you're right. Spaces are rather meaningless in this case.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, you are correct. Sorry for forgetting those obvious examples.